Is It Possible to Use PyModbus to Communicate with Sensors Connected to a Beckhoff PLC (CX7080) via RS-485 Modbus RTU?
I have connected sensors to the RS-485 port on my Beckhoff PLC (CX7080) and successfully read their registers using Modbus RTU via TwinCAT. Initially, I considered using PyADS to communicate with the PLC, but realized that PyADS requires TwinCAT for ADS communication, which I want to avoid in this case.
Now, I’m exploring the possibility of developing an application that directly communicates with the sensors connected to the Beckhoff PLC (CX7080) over Modbus RS-485 using the PyModbus library in Python.
My questions are:
Is it possible to use PyModbus to communicate directly with the sensors through the Beckhoff PLC’s RS-485 port (without TwinCAT or ADS)?
If yes, what would be the best approach to implement this?

Should the PLC act as a Modbus RTU master and expose data via Modbus TCP?
Can PyModbus directly interact with the sensors via the PLC’s serial interface?

Any guidance, examples, or resources would be greatly appreciated!
Tried reading the register values of sensors using TwinCAT. Is it possible to develop an appplication using Pymodbus that interacts with sensors via beckhoff plc(cx7080)? The requests are sent to the PLC via ethernet but not com port.

take a look at the Virtual COm Port https://www.beckhoff.com/en-en/products/automation/twincat/tfxxxx-twincat-3-functions/tf6xxx-connectivity/tf6360.html, this may do what you need?

You could also use something like MQTT https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf6701_tc3_iot_communication_mqtt/index.html&id=4400404359336298224  or OPC-UA to be a coordinator between the python and Beckhoff PLC

You also don't need the full install of TwinCAT (engineering or runtime), just the TwinCAT ADS version to be able to establish communication over Python. Which may make it more palatable to install on your PC running python. Using ADS is defienetly simpler than the other methods.

Thanks for your reply. I am now using Pyads to communicate with the PLC directly and TwinCAT to only program, configure the PLC.
